# Deploy Magento Install from Master Copy

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anyone use or know of any solutions for deploying a magento site from a master copy?

Reason is, I produce a number of magento sites, and have a number of extensions I use each time, which need installing and often bug fixing to get them all to work together, and I have to do this each and every time I create a new site.

Is it possible for me to have a master magento install somewhere, and use this as my starting point each time I want to create a new site?

I'm using v1.9 if that's relevant.

Comment: i don't think so but you can use  git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have it in a git repo, then clone it down into a new project and then do your developments and push it to a new repo.

For example:

In github you could have MyMasterMagento

then when you do git clone you can

```
git clone {clone url for MyMasterMagento} projectA
```

Then for the next project do the same thing but change the project name

```
git clone {clone url for MyMasterMagento} projectB
```